# Ignoring the slash in a variable that I want to join to file path

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of currency pairs that I want to create separate folders for and drop a csv into it:
def symbols():

```
symbols = ['AUD/CAD' 'AUD/JPY' 'AUD/NZD' 'AUD/USD' 'CAD/JPY' 'EUR/AUD' 'EUR/CAD'
           'EUR/CHF' 'EUR/GBP' 'EUR/JPY' 'EUR/NOK' 'EUR/SEK' 'EUR/USD' 'GBP/AUD'
           'GBP/CAD' 'GBP/CHF' 'GBP/JPY' 'GBP/USD' 'NZD/JPY' 'NZD/USD' 'USD/CAD'
           'USD/CHF' 'USD/DKK' 'USD/HKD' 'USD/ILS' 'USD/JPY' 'USD/MXN' 'USD/NOK'
           'USD/SEK' 'USD/SGD' 'USD/ZAR']
```

When I run the code below, instead of creating a path similar to "C:\Symbols\AUD/USD", it creates a file path that seperates the pair into two folders like this "C:\Symbols\AUD\USD"

I realize the slash is messing this up, I'm just not sure how to ignore it without replacing the "/" with another character.

```
def symbols():

    global df
    symbols = np.unique(df[['Symbol']].values)

    for symbol in symbols:
        xs = df[df.Symbol == symbol]
        if not os.path.exists(symbol):
            os.makedirs(symbol)
        with open(symbol + '\\data.csv ', "a") as f:
            if os.path.getsize(symbol + '\\data.csv ') > 0:
                xs.to_csv(f, sep=",", index=False, header=False)
            else:
                xs.to_csv(f, sep=",", index=False)
```

Comment: Do you **really** need to use that slash? I think that using a different character (e.g. ``-``) would not only solve your problem but also make the thing portable to non-windows systems, less prone to errors and mistakes...

Comment: `xs = df[df.Symbol == symbol]` -- what type of object is df?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig I guess `df` is  pandas `DataFrame`

Comment: I'd suggest dropping those slashes altogether as generally accepted practice in Finance is to name currency pairs without them. `EURUSD` would mean `EUR` expressed in `USD`.  See http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURUSD:CUR e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Forward slashes `/` are generally not allowed in folder names. Try replacing it with `-` or `.`

Have a look at [Special characters in files and folder names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code without seeing  `symbols`, the line

```
os.makedirs(symbol)
```

will make a directory for  `AUD` *and* `USD` *each*. If you want this to be *one* directy, call `os.makedirs` for a pair, not for a single symbol.